# Calculating population of only urban areas from a raster layer

Tags: raster, arcmap, population

I have a raster file of population data downloaded from [www.worldpop.org](http://www.worldpop.org).
I also have a shape file of township polygons but what I am trying to do is to only
calculate population of urban areas not rural areas in each township.
I tried the following way (although, it didn't work).

1. Add lat,long points of urban areas
2. Convert raster population layer to point
3. Spatial join from step 1 and step 2.

How can I successfully calculate urban areas' population only?

Comment: Such action is usually called an extraction. I think the tool you are looking for is the [extract raster](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/extract-raster.htm) tool.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: Actually, I am using ArcMap.

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot @ChloeG. I have tried in this following way and it works.

1. Create a empty shape file.
2. Create features via polygon from Editor tool.
3. Place the polygon based on Region of Interests (ROI).
4. Extract desired raster data from Spatial Analyst Tools->Extraction->Extract by Mask, where Mask is polygon shape file.
5. Calculate zonal statistics from Spatial Analyst Tools->Zonal->Zonal Statistics as Table.